# coordinates2politics: Reverse Geocoding does not work correctly

Tags: r, maps, geocoding

I'm working on a data frame of latitudes and longitudes values to get the corresponding address using the `coordinates2politics` function available in the data science toolkit.
The function works well for a single lat&long value, but when I parsing an array in the body of a `POST` call it doesn't work.

Code snippet:

```
x <- data.frame(lat= c(35.18713,37.86058),long= c(-117.88536,-122.29673))
data <- paste0("[",paste(paste0("\"",x$lat,"%2c",x$long,"\""),collapse=","),"]")
url  <- "http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/coordinates2politics/"
response <- POST(url,body=data)
response
json     <- fromJSON(content(response,type="text"))
json
```

The resulted places are for a different lat and long values, and I don't know why?
Here is the result for the first input, you can observe that lat = 51, long=53 !!

```
json
[[1]]
[[1]]$politics
[[1]]$politics[[1]]
[[1]]$politics[[1]]$type
[1] "admin2"

[[1]]$politics[[1]]$friendly_type
[1] "country"

[[1]]$politics[[1]]$name
[1] "Kazakhstan"

[[1]]$politics[[1]]$code
[1] "kaz"


[[1]]$politics[[2]]
[[1]]$politics[[2]]$type
[1] "admin4"

[[1]]$politics[[2]]$friendly_type
[1] "state"

[[1]]$politics[[2]]$name
[1] "West Kazakhstan"

[[1]]$politics[[2]]$code
[1] "kz07"

[[1]]$location
[[1]]$location$latitude
[1] 51

[[1]]$location$longitude
[1] 53
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution
The problem was in defining the `data` object as the function needs an array of two key values each correspondes to  `[lat,long]` pairs
so the data object should be defined as
`data <- paste0("[",paste(paste0("[",x$lat,",",x$long,"]"),collapse=","),`"]")